# Not able to open txt file with Drivenotepad app in google drive

Tags: google-drive, notepad

I have plain text file named "version.txt" saved in my google drive. When i open this with particular "Drive Notepad" app from right click menu, it gives me message **Authorization required** , don't know why drive notepad gives authorization error, while i am still login!!

Does any one face this issue ?

Because previously there were no issues opening same file with drive notepad app.

EDIT : console log outputs below text while opening file

```
app.js:393 Loading default/localStorage settings...
app.js:475 [user settings] ext: txt
all.build.js:4 [user settings] wordWrap: true,,
all.build.js:4 [user settings] wordWrapAt: 80
all.build.js:4 [user settings] fontSize: 1
all.build.js:4 [user settings] widget_anchor: r,5.34407027818448,b,11.604940155406057
all.build.js:4 [user settings] showGutterHistory: 1
all.build.js:4 [user settings] lastDNVersionUsed: 
all.build.js:4 [user settings] newLineDefault: windows
all.build.js:4 [user settings] historyRemovedIsExpanded: true
all.build.js:4 [user settings] softTabN: 4
all.build.js:4 [user settings] tabIsHard: 0
all.build.js:4 [user settings] widgetSub: general
all.build.js:4 [user settings] theme: chrome
all.build.js:4 [user settings] pane: pane_help
all.build.js:4 [user settings] pane_open: true
all.build.js:4 [user settings] find_regex: false
all.build.js:4 [user settings] find_whole_words: false
all.build.js:4 [user settings] find_case_sensitive: false
all.build.js:4 [user settings] help_inner: main
all.build.js:4 [user settings] find_goto: false
all.build.js:4 [user settings] find_replace: false
all.build.js:2 Strangely structured error:
all.build.js:2 Object
client_id:"591525900269-94ok9krafau8qa24666btvccmsfnq5fp.apps.googleusercontent.com"
cookie_policy:"single_host_origin"
error:"immediate_failed"
error_subtype:"access_denied"
response_type:undefined
status:Object
google_logged_in:false
method:null
signed_in:false
all.build.js:3 Error. See developer console for details.
all.build.js:4 [user settings] 
widget_anchor:l,8.784773060029282,t,16.420077433628318
```

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/drive/FU3VmbOsb94/Vvc6u6I2BQAJ)

Comment: Tried but still same authorization error, not able to open.

Comment: Tried in INCOGNITO  window also, but same access denied error, dont know, while  opening in new tab console shows **google_logged_in:false** & **error_subtype:"access_denied"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i have found something strange in browser url while opening txt file with drivenotepad app.

URL seems to be like this

```
https://drivenotepad.github.io/app/?state=%7B"ids":%5B"1RvRuTWDSUIl1ritooHDWLUtZg0BR3iL-"%5D,"action":"open","userId":"{userId}"%7D
```

Its showing `"userId":"{userId}"` so i entered my email-id  like `"userId":"xxxx@mygmaildomain.com"` & reloaded page.

Now text file opened successfully in drivenotepad app with text contents.

Also got success logs console:

```
   [user settings] ext: txt
app.js:475 [user settings] wordWrap: true,,
app.js:475 [user settings] wordWrapAt: 80
app.js:475 [user settings] fontSize: 1
app.js:475 [user settings] widget_anchor: l,8.784773060029282,t,16.420077433628318
app.js:475 [user settings] showGutterHistory: 1
app.js:475 [user settings] lastDNVersionUsed: 
app.js:475 [user settings] newLineDefault: windows
app.js:475 [user settings] historyRemovedIsExpanded: true
app.js:475 [user settings] softTabN: 4
app.js:475 [user settings] tabIsHard: 0
app.js:475 [user settings] widgetSub: general
app.js:475 [user settings] theme: chrome
app.js:475 [user settings] pane: pane_help
app.js:475 [user settings] pane_open: true
app.js:475 [user settings] find_regex: false
app.js:475 [user settings] find_whole_words: false
app.js:475 [user settings] find_case_sensitive: false
app.js:475 [user settings] help_inner: main
app.js:475 [user settings] find_goto: false
app.js:475 [user settings] find_replace: false
succeeded getting user info.
app.js:429 Transfering to realtime model for settings.
app.js:475 [user settings] widget_anchor: r,5.34407027818448,b,11.604940155406057
app.js:475 [user settings] lastDNVersionUsed: 2016a
app.js:1042 succeeded loading settings
app.js:1011 succeeded loading file body and metadata.
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer. Between don't forget to report the bug [here](https://plus.google.com/communities/107691649945880497995).

Comment: It's showing me a string of number rather than `"{userId}"`, and replacing it with my `"xxx@gmail.com"` address didnt fix it

Answer (score 0):

A Tampermonkey Solution

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         DriveNotepad
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  WorkAround For DriveNotepad
// @author       SmartManoj
// @match        https://drivenotepad.github.io/app/*userId%22:*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    var mail_id="...";
    var url=window.location.href;
    var newUrl = url.replace(/userId[%:\d]*%7D/i,"userId%22:%22"+mail_id+"%22%7D");
    console.log(newUrl);
    if (url!=newUrl)window.location.href=newUrl;
    // Your code here...
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click and choose 'Preview' to read it.  There is a pulldown at the tope that defaults to 'Drive Notebook'.  Pull down to 'Google Docs' option.  File will be converted and opened for editing.