# How to grant google drive applications rights to edit documents?

Tags: google-drive, authorization

I'm trying to edit some Google Drive documents with 3rd party applications (notably Drivenotepad). When starting the application, it reports an error ("Error: see developer console for details"). In the developer console, the following log appears:

```
Strangely structured error:
using_apis.js:95 Object
    client_id: "<bla bla bla ...>.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    cookie_policy: "single_host_origin"
    error: "immediate_failed"
    error_subtype: "access_denied"
    response_type: undefined
    status: {signed_in: false, method: null, google_logged_in: false}
    __proto__: Object
app.js:131 Error. See developer console for details.
```

I suspect that some authorization was revoked to the app, but I'm not able to grant it again (for example, at https://myaccount.google.com/permissions it's possible to revoke permissions, but not to add them).

Note: I also checked a similar question: [Not able to open txt file with Drivenotepad app in google drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1293702/not-able-to-open-txt-file-with-drivenotepad-app-in-google-drive/1293718) but it seems not to address the same problem.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a problem of the 3rd party application (Drive Notepad), due to the use of an API that has been deprecated. No way to workaround the problem.